# Why does "xxx::function();" not work but "using namespace xxx; function();" does?

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces, boost-graph, argument-dependent-lookup

I am using Boost's graph C++ library, and I stumbled over a problem when asking for the number of vertices of a grid graph.

The following code snipped creates a 2-dimensional grid graph of shape 5 by 6, and then prints the number of vertices of that graph, which is `5x6 = 30`.
However, this does not compile with the error:

> error: ‘num_vertices’ is not a member of ‘boost’

```cpp
#include <boost/graph/grid_graph.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::grid_graph<2> Graph;
    Graph g({5, 6});
    std::cout << "Num vertices: " << boost::num_vertices(g) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I change the code to include `using namespace boost;` at the beginning, then it does work:

```cpp
#include <boost/graph/grid_graph.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

int main()
{
    typedef grid_graph<2> Graph;
    Graph g({5, 6});
    std::cout << "Num vertices: " << num_vertices(g) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Curiously, this is not a problem when I use a different Boost graph type, like `boost::adjacency_list<>`.

So I have three questions:

1. Which operating principle of namespaces causes this behavior?
2. Regarding the special case of the grid graph implementation in Boost: Is this a bug or is this intended behavior?
3. Is there any way I can call the `num_vertices` function without the `using` directive?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in either of those code examples needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: There is a third option - don't use either `using namespace` or a `boost::` prefix. That lets ADL find the function. A qualified name disables ADL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/graph/doc/VertexListGraph.html, this function must be called as `num_vertices(g)`.

It is probably implemented as a "hidden friend function", meaning it can only be found via argument-dependent lookup.

Comment: That's it.  The hidden friend function is a thunk routine that calls the protected member function of the same name.

Comment: @Eljay basically. Though calling it a member function van be unnecessarily confusing: it's a friend (ie. static by definition) function declared within the class scope

Comment: @sehe • The non-member hidden friend function calls a protected member function.

Comment: @Eljay typically, not necessarily. Also, that non -static member is not usually by the same name anyways.

Comment: @sehe • I was referring to this `num_vertices` case in particular.  I concur with you, that in the general case there are no requirements like this, no constraints, and no impositions.  Not even an informal convention (that I'm aware of).